# Use of --shift-heading-level-by=-1 in Haskell code

Tags: pandoc

I would like to use the pandoc extension `--shift-heading-level-by` in a program written in Haskell. I searched the documentation for reader options and extensions (for version 2.17.1.1), but cannot find anything to have this effect. Usually, pandoc extensions are listed in the extensions and can be accessed from Haskell code.

I could write a filter, following the example given in [question](https://Pandoc%20:%20set%20document%20title%20to%20first%20title) but I prefere to avoid duplication of code, if ever possible. Therefore:
What is the name of the extension for `--shift-heading-level-by` and in which version is it introduced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function that is named `Text.Pandoc.Shared.headerShift` and was introduced in pandoc 1.6. It is applied whenever `--shift-heading-level-by` is passed as an argument.

Comment: thank you very much! I never checked this directory and found - besides the function I looked for - a lot of other useful utilities. Great stuff!